# Триггеры в WPF (Анимация отображения окна)

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени, Хешкодовцы.

Начал изучать WPF, дошел до триггеров. Пытаюсь несколько самостоятельно задачек решить, поставленных собой же, т.к. примеры в книге очень простые, и хочется что-то более реальное для использования в жизни.

Собственно первая задачка заключается в анимации отображения окна. Хочу, чтобы когда окно отображается на экране, оно плавно выезжало из-за границ экрана, здесь у меня несколько проблем возникло:

- Не могу понять, куда триггер впихать. Пытаюсь в раздел <Window> </Window>, ругается, что сюда нельзя, т.к. он уже есть (но что-то его в коде я не наблюдаю). Пытался в Grid - здесь ругается, что он не может содержать триггер... Еще появилась идея поместить его в стиль, но с ними пока у меня не совсем все понятно.
- Как получить размеры экрана, чтобы предустановить положение окна в зависимости от разрешения экрана (хочу, чтобы окно справа выползало). Ну пока вполне пример сойдет, чтобы окно слева выползало. Задал константные значения слева.

Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы.

Answer (score 4):

Костыли-костылики:

Позиция остановки окна задается в процентах от ширины экрана (WindowPosition, 30 в данном случае).

В этой строчке:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_test"
```

"wpf_test" надо будет заменить на тип вашей формы.

```
<Window x:Class="wpf_test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_test"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
    x:Name="MySlidingWindow">

<Window.Resources>
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="WindowPosition">30</sys:Int32>
    <local:WindowPositionConverter x:Key="WindowPosConv" />
</Window.Resources>

<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded" SourceName="MySlidingWindow">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MySlidingWindow"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Left"
                        From="{x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth}"
                        To="{Binding Source={StaticResource WindowPosition}, Converter={StaticResource WindowPosConv}}"
                        Duration="0:0:1.5"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Далее код конвертора:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace wpf_test
{
    class WindowPositionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var pos = (int) value;
            var result = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth/100*pos;
            return result;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот такая простыня кода.